# How can I see added last candle in candlestick chart with WinForms Chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

Sorry, I'm not good at writing with English.

I've tried to make real time candle stick chart and almost completed.
But, there are a few problems.

1. When new data comes in, my program works, but it only shows half the width of the last candle.
   I can then move the scroll bar to the end to see the finished bar. I don't know where to touch.
2. When the chart area is zoomed, the length of the x-axis changes slightly when data is received.
   I want to fix the size of the area where the candle is displayed.

The following are some of the sources:

private void RealChart(Chart chart)
{
int a = chtMain.Series["BaseCandle"].Points.Count;

```
        double yMinValue = double.MaxValue;
        double yMaxValue = double.MinValue;

        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            Series s = chtMain.Series["BaseCandle"];
            if (i < s.Points.Count)
            {
                yMaxValue = Math.Max(yMaxValue, s.Points[i].YValues[0]);
                yMinValue = Math.Min(yMinValue, s.Points[i].YValues[1]);
            }
        }
                    
        chtMain.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Maximum = yMaxValue + Math.Abs(yMaxValue * 0.05);
        chtMain.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Minimum = yMinValue - Math.Abs(yMinValue * 0.05);

        chtMain.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScaleView.Scroll(a);
    }
```

Comment: Note that the margin partial setting is true.

Comment: Try setting `IsMarginVisible=true;` You also need to revert to automatic scaling: `yourAxis.Minimum = double.NaN;... `